# Why are you not supposed to modify the DOM with deferred scripts?

Tags: javascript, dom, deferred-execution

I'm brushing up on my javascript basics, and the book I'm reading stated the following (paraphrased):

*"Adding the defer attribute the script element is a promise to the browser that your script will not be making any changes to the DOM"*

I was curious as to why this is so? Since deferred scripts aren't executed until after rendering is complete, I would assume that it is safe to modify the DOM in your script.

Comment: "Professional Javascript" by Nicholas Zakas, and it's also mentioned here: http://www.sitepoint.com/non-blocking-async-defer/

Comment: I think that was just poorly worded, and is intended to mean you promise not to use document.write within the script. There's nothing wrong with making minor dom changes after the page has loaded, just don't make major ones or you'll get a FOUC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a confusion of terminology about what "the DOM" means. Consulting the [HTML4 spec on `defer`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#adef-defer) gives us a hint about what's really going on:

> When set, this boolean attribute provides a hint to the user agent that the script is not going to generate any document content (e.g., no "`document.write`" in javascript) and thus, the user agent can continue parsing and rendering.

So, what your book means by

> your script will not be making changes to the DOM

is really

> your script will not be making changes to the **document text being parsed**

Your paraphrased quote uses the phrase "the DOM" to refer to the HTML document text being parsed, instead of the JavaScript-accessible *object model* being created by that parsing. There is no reason why your defered script could not alter the DOM structure (i.e., the one in `document`) after being parsed, but it certainly cannot alter the document text being parsed, since the document has already been fully parsed when the script runs.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. Looking back at the book I notice that it doesn't say "DOM", this was just an assumption I made. The exact quote is "The purpose of defer is to indicate that a script won't be changing the structure of the page as it executes". Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: I had the same doubt of the author of topic. Thanks you for your clarification.